# SQL plus 2 column data inside count

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I try get result 3 ,  5 without count Duplicate , NUll value and Empty data.

```
    select count(distinct no1), count(distinct no1) + count(distinct no2) from abc where no1 
    is not null
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i don't want include null and empty in count. want result 3   5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want null and empty, try this:

```
select
   count(distinct case when no1 = '' then null else no1 end),
   count(distinct case when no1 = '' then null else no1 end)
   + count(distinct case when no2 = '' then null else no2 end)
from `tbl`
```

See [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fda92/3) here.

***Explain***: `count`, `sum`, `avg` etc... Like these aggregation functions will not take `null` as its calculational object. So just turn the empty value to `null`, here use `case when` to do it, then `count distinct` will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct no1), count(distinct no1) + (select  count(distinct no2) from abc where no2 is not null and no2<>'') from abc where no1 is not null
```

Try this

Comment: Not working, it comes out error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'." and "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Comment: Now i changed the query try again